# Double string format

Tags: python, string, format

I'm trying to do a 'double string format' in python. It's just a formatted string with a value of another formatted string. This is and example of what I'm doing:

```
a = ['%d{t}' % i for i in range(3)]
b = '{nums}'.format(t='-', nums=''.join(a))
print b
```

This is the result:

```
0{t}1{t}2{t}
```

But I want this:

```
0-1-2-
```

EDIT: I'm using python from Visual Studio 2015, idk its version.

Comment: A better question... why? What do you gain from doing this?

Answer (score 2):

To minimize changes to your code:

```
a = ['%d{t}' % i for i in range(3)]
b = '{nums}'.format(nums=''.join(a)).format(t='-')
print b
```

### Why yours failed

You can't double replace `{}`, meaning that if you replace `{num}` with `{t}`, it won't then process `{t}`.

### Why mine works

I made it so it executes one replacement at a time.  First it does the `{num}` **then** it does the `{t}`

Comment: Just format it after you finished it? Can you give me an example, I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: If I edit b with:
b = '{t}{nums}'.format(nums=''.join(a)).format(t='-')
't' will not format. 't' is a string randomly generated. I'll better modify the code logic to no get stuck by this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It still works:  `{nums}'.format(nums=''.join(a)).format(t='-')`